# API Versions & Test Class Speed

Tags: unit-test, deployment

We're currently having a minor problem with the speed at which test classes run. We've got quite a lot of tests, around 300+ run during deployments. However, this can take anywhere between 30 minutes and an hour to deploy which seems quite extensive. Particularly if something was to fail for some unforeseen reason. One thing I have picked up on is that the API Version of our classes and test classes go as far back as Version 23.0.

What I'm interested to know is:

- Is this deployment time normal for so many test classes?
- Could API versions of classes and test classes affect deployment times
- Can Meta Data be deployed into production (currently using Sublime Text 3 + Mavensmate) to change the API version
- Would deploying Meta Data potentially break anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Is this deployment time normal for so many test classes?

It does seem high for 300 tests but you would need to look at how long it took each test to run. You may have some tests that are taking a long time to run.

- Could API versions of classes and test classes affect deployment times

Yes, if a test is using API 23 or less then that test will see all data in the org which will cause your SOQL queries to return more records than you expected.

- Can Meta Data be deployed into production (currently using Sublime Text 3 + Mavensmate) to change the API version

Yes

- Would deploying Meta Data potentially break anything?

Yes, tests can fail and logic may not work as expected.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like this could be a bit of a nightmare to resolve although it's not desperate as of yet. Good to know a fix option is available though.